# Using preg_match to extract a string within a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$data = '| years_active = 1960â€“70 | label = ';
preg_match('active(.*?)label', $data, $matches);
echo print_r($matches);
```

I was expecting this to output an array containing the value: ' = 1960â€“70 | ', but I just get the output: 1.

Ideally, I am trying to extract just: '1960â€“70'.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your echoing the result of print_r(), "If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return the information rather than print it."  http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

You also need to pre-define $matches as preg_match takes the ref to that array and you botched the regex: `'/active(.*)label/'`

```
<?php
$matches = array();
$data = '| years_active = 1960â€“70 | label = ';
preg_match('/active(.*)label/', $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```